# automatically switching system language in ASP.NET text box

Tags: asp.net

I'm using VS2010,C# to develop my ASP.NET web app, I'm creating a Persian (Farsi, Iran) web site that users should enter Persian words, is there any way that system typing language is automatically changed to Farsi when users switch to text boxes? Currently they should press ALT+SHIFT to switch languages

thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: "No". You can't switch keyboard language on a client. But you can simulate this with replacing characters typed by user to appropriate Farsi characters on textbox keyup event.

Look at RETYPE jquery plugin for example: [RETYPE](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/retype)